# while searching for a number in dataframe, it shows :argument of type 'numpy.int64' is not iterable. how to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I  want to search a number in a  column . if the number is found it will store the corresponding path to a list . so my target number is 159 , and my expected output should be corresponding repeating paths , as the number 159 repeats 151 times.But,it shows the error: argument of type 'numpy.int64' is not iterable, how can I fix it ?

```
i=0
charpath0 = []
item = '159'
for x in range(len(df)):
  if item in df.grapheme_root[x]:
    s= (df.path[x])
    charpath0.append(s)
    i=i+1

csv file looks like this :

image_id    grapheme_root   vowel_diacritic consonant_diacritic grapheme    path    Total_graphemes
0   Train_0 15  9   5   ক্ট্রো  ../input/fulldata/train_images128/train_images...   164
1   Train_1 159 0   0   হ   ../input/fulldata/train_images128/train_images...   151
2   Train_2 22  3   5   খ্রী    ../input/fulldata/train_images128/train_images...   143
3   Train_3 53  2   2   র্টি    ../input/fulldata/train_images128/train_images...   162
4   Train_4 71  9   5   থ্রো    ../input/fulldata/train_images128/train_images...   164
```

Comment: Are you looking for `df.loc[df['grapheme_root']==159]['path'].values`

Comment: @Chris , this gives me all combination values of grapheme_root , vowel_diacritic, and consonant_diacritic . But i am looking for the repeating value where the combination isonly (159, 0 ,0) for the column of grapheme_root , vowel_diacritic, and consonant_diacritic. how can i do that ?

Comment: i think   df.loc[(df['grapheme_root'] == 159) & (df['vowel_diacritic']==0) & (df['consonant_diacritic']==0).values]  this is the solution